# Youtube Analytics API 及び Reporting API の使用制限 (クォータ) が存在するのか知りたい

Tags: youtube

Youtube Analytics APIとReporting APIの使用制限について、公式ドキュメントのリンクも切れており、把握できませんでした。
Youtube Data APIは1日10,000クウォーターの制限がありますが、Youtube Analytics APIとReporting APIの制限についてご存知でしたらご教示頂きたいです。

Answer (score 0):

少なくとも YouTube Analytics API には quota が存在します: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/data_model

> Each API request that you make counts as one unit of your API usage quota. Quota limits are visible on the [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com) panel in the Google API Console.